How to combine many different factor levels into a limited number of factor levels?
I'm working on summarising a column of data about the village from which participants hail. The information arrived as character variables, which I've changed into factors.
There are about ~30 different villages represented. Some are just mispellings - eg. Chicago and Chicgao.
I wanted to summarise this info into factors levels A, B, C, D and Other, where A is village A and all mispellings of village A, and Other is everything else that doesn't fit into A-D. (The number of mispellings are limited, thankfully.)
I have no idea how to do this other than manually recoding a lot of data points.
df %>%
  mutate(x= recode(x, "c('A', 'misspeltA')='A'; c('E', 'F', 'G' ... 'Z') = 'Other'))

I've also tried
df$village <- factor(df$village,
                       levels =c("A","B","C","mispeltA","D","E","F"),
                       labels =c("A","B","C","A","D","Other","Other"))

Is there a faster way?

If these are limited number of factor levels you may check ?case_when

Look at the phonics package.

forcats::fct_collapse() might help a bit:
library(dplyr)
set.seed(42)
df_ <- tibble(x = c("misspeltA", LETTERS[1:9]))

df_ |> 
  mutate( 
    x_collapsed = forcats::fct_collapse(x,
      A = c('A', 'misspeltA'), 
      B = c('B'), 
      C = c('C'), 
      D = c('D'), 
      other_level = "Other"
      )
    ) 
#> # A tibble: 10 × 2
#>    x         x_collapsed
#>    <chr>     <fct>      
#>  1 misspeltA A          
#>  2 A         A          
#>  3 B         B          
#>  4 C         C          
#>  5 D         D          
#>  6 E         Other      
#>  7 F         Other      
#>  8 G         Other      
#>  9 H         Other      
#> 10 I         Other


You can also build a named list of levels that can be spliced (!!!) and passed to fct_collapse(); for example wrangle villages vector so it would be suitable as a starting point (perhaps sort unique values alphabetically or by number of occurrences), create a named list and use dput() output as a base for manual edit:
sort(df_$x) |> 
  unique() |> 
  purrr::set_names() |> 
  as.list() |> 
  dput()

#> list(A = "A", B = "B", C = "C", D = "D", E = "E", F = "F", G = "G", 
#>     H = "H", I = "I", misspeltA = "misspeltA")

lvl <- 
  list(
    A = c("A", "misspeltA"), 
    B = "B", C = "C", D = "D"
  )

df_ |> 
  mutate(x_collapsed = forcats::fct_collapse(x, !!!lvl, other_level = "Other")) 
#> # A tibble: 10 × 2
#>    x         x_collapsed
#>    <chr>     <fct>      
#>  1 misspeltA A          
#>  2 A         A          
#>  3 B         B          
#>  4 C         C          
#>  5 D         D          
#>  6 E         Other      
#>  7 F         Other      
#>  8 G         Other      
#>  9 H         Other      
#> 10 I         Other


An automatic approach combining similar information into a new grp using agrep.
If this is your data
cities <- c("Chicgo", "Atalanta", "Chicago", "Chicgao", "Atlanta", "Atlnata",
"Boston", "Botson")

Regrouping with agrep
sapply(cities, \(x) 
  paste(agrep(x, cities, max.distance=3), collapse=""))
  Chicgo Atalanta  Chicago  Chicgao  Atlanta  Atlnata   Boston   Botson
   "134"    "256"    "134"    "134"    "256"    "256"     "78"     "78"

as a data.frame
data.frame(cities, grp = 
  sapply(cities, \(x) 
    paste(agrep(x, cities, max.distance=3), collapse="")), row.names=NULL)
    cities grp
1   Chicgo 134
2 Atalanta 256
3  Chicago 134
4  Chicgao 134
5  Atlanta 256
6  Atlnata 256
7   Boston  78
8   Botson  78

Note that you can play around with max.distance, taking higher values if more dissimilarities should be combined (with the trade off that some false combinations may occur).
